# definition of $X$ in bold in a regression equation

Tags: regression, data-analysis

About question 1.1 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.09169.pdf

Here are two sorts of $X$, namely a bold one and a normal one.
Usually when I see a regression equation I see $Y = \mbox{**X**}\beta$, but can't use it in this situation. Here they write $Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1X$ and they don't define **X**.

Does anyone have a definition of which he knows that this is probably what they mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In $Y = X\beta + \epsilon$ notations, $X$ is an $n\times p$ matrix, while in $ Y = \beta_0 + \beta X + \epsilon$, $X$ usually denotes variable (not necessarily random). In your case, they explicitly stated that $X$ is a variable that were sampled $8$ times, namely its values were $X=(−2, −1, −1, −1, 0, 1, 2, 2)^⊤$.

Comment: Pls see the edited answer

Comment: You mean the non-bold $X$? Then what about **X**?

Comment: $X$ is a (random) variables, $\mathrm{X}$ is a vector of its $8$ realizations.

Comment: So **X** $^T$ **X** is just a real number (actually a $1\times 1$ matrix). Ok, the solution of this exercise however says that **X** $^T$ **X** $= \begin{pmatrix} 8 & 0 \\ 0 & 16 \end{pmatrix}$ and **X** $Y$ $= \begin{pmatrix} 320 \\ 35 \end{pmatrix}$. Maybe I should have written this before.

Comment: Well. $\mathrm{X}$ contains also a columns of $1$'s for the intercept, thus the $(x'x)_{11} = n = 8$.

Comment: Ah ok! In this way it becomes clear